# Unable to resolve module ./assets/ send. png from /Users/chrisscutie/SendGo/SendGoApp/ src/components/screens/Signup.js:

Tags: reactjs, expo

[This is what i built in the App.js file before moving it to a component folder][This is the error i am getting after putting it in a component folder and exporting[This is how the Screen looks when i remove or comment out the image file.[This is my App.js File[This is my WelocmeScreen file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSFX1.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlf8c.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVERC.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjYJ8.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/T75CL.png) [This is how my assets library looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PM0P.png)

Hello everyone I’m new to frontend and I’m facing this issue regarding images. The images were showing fine on the screen when I was doing everything in the App.js file. But it stopped working after moving it to a component folder and and exported it. If I remove the image the rest of the contents on the screen shows but it gives me error when I add the image. can you help me on how what could be wrong and how I can import an image correctly? Thanks

Images are not working when I moved code into a component folder

Comment: Hey Chris, This really isn't the optimal format question for stack overflow. What I'd recommend is breaking this down into the absolute minimal example that shows the issue and then post it as a new question. If you can illustrate with just HTML and CSS even better.

Comment: As a quick fix, you could try importing instead of using require.
`import Send from './send.png';` For whatever reason, your require can't resolve it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks guys, ive been able to solve it this way source={require('../screens/assets/send.png')}